# SQL - collapse multiple rows into one based on a set of CASE statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a SQL query, how can I collapse a set of results into one row where each result is the product of a particular `CASE`? Surely my example will help to illustrate the question I'm trying to ask...

I'm running a query against a Postgres table that returns groups of survey answers - the survey is short, just 4 questions, and each question has a unique `question_id` - since multiple surveys can be submitted, the `question_id` field itself does not enforce uniqueness, and will have repeating values where each set of repeated values represents one full survey response. For example, here is `survey_answers`:

```
question_id  |    answer
----------------------------
     a       |     10
     b       |     foo
     c       |     9
     d       |     bar
     a       |     2
     b       |     baz
     c       |     4
     d       |     zip
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to query/process this result even further into an output where each set of results is collapsed into one row:

```
score_1  |  reason_1  |  score_2  |  reason_2
----------------------------------------------
   10    |    foo     |     9     |    bar
   2     |    baz     |     4     |    zip
```

However, I'm not so adept at SQL and I can't quite get this to work. The closest that I can get is using this query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN survey_answers.question_id = 'a' THEN survey_answers.answer END AS score_1,
    CASE WHEN survey_answers.question_id = 'b' THEN survey_answers.answer END AS reason_1,
    CASE WHEN survey_answers.question_id = 'c' THEN survey_answers.answer END AS score_2,
    CASE WHEN survey_answers.question_id = 'd' THEN survey_answers.answer END AS reason_2
FROM survey_answers
```

but this produces a table where each result is on its own line (I'm not surprised by this result - just not sure how to get it into what I'm looking for):

```
score_1  |  reason_1  |  score_2  |  reason_2
----------------------------------------------
   10    |    NULL    |    NULL   |   NULL
   NULL  |    foo     |    NULL   |   NULL
   NULL  |    NULL    |    9      |   NULL
   NULL  |    NULL    |    NULL   |   bar
   2     |    NULL    |    NULL   |   NULL
   NULL  |    baz     |    NULL   |   NULL
   NULL  |    NULL    |    4      |   NULL
   NULL  |    NULL    |    NULL   |   zip
```

How can I query `survey_answers` so that each group is collapsed into one row?

Comment: you just need to aggregate each one - `max(case when ...)`.

Comment: Or a subselect for each column in a one row  select without from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  What you really need, though, is not ordering but a column that specifies a particular set of answers.  Let's call this `responder_id`.

Then, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT sa.responder_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sa.question_id = 'a' THEN sa.answer END) AS score_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sa.question_id = 'b' THEN sa.answer END) AS reason_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sa.question_id = 'c' THEN sa.answer END) AS score_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sa.question_id = 'd' THEN sa.answer END) AS reason_2
FROM survey_answers sa
GROUP BY sa.reponder_id;
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much - I was able to include a `responder_id` column in the results from the initial query that generated the `survey_responses`, and so I could use that to handle the grouping. Otherwise, the MAX() worked perfectly.